# Websphere cluster member to stop/start request processing

Tags: request, websphere, websphere-7

Is there a way to stop/start send request directed to member of a websphere cluster?

The use-case is

- Stop the member
- Stop request directed to a cluster member (Anyway the cluster member will be notified, hence no request will be directed)
- Start cluster member
- Wait for application server (member) to stablize
- The start request direction

Any help, would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

One way to prevent cluster members from receiving requests is to set the "member weight" to zero. I would slightly modify your use case to the following:

1. Take note of the current "member weight" of the cluster member.
2. Set the "member weight" for the cluster member to zero. Do this in the configuration and sync the node where the member is running.
3. Stop the cluster member.
4. Start the cluster member.
5. Wait for the server to stabilize.
6. Set the "member weight" for the cluster member back to it's original value. Do this in both in the configuration and the runtime.

Information about how to change the cluster member weight can be found here: 
http://www14.software.ibm.com/webapp/wsbroker/redirect?version=compass&product=was-nd-dist&topic=urun_rwlm_member

Gary

Comment: Not sure modification of "member weight" is allowed in runtime... can you confirm